# Why isn' t this selecting and changing the attributes in D3?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a simple data object called data that contains some radii , co-ordinates and colours I wish to use for my circles. However I want to now make them all orange but the last line of code does not seem to run ?

```
const myCircles = svg.selectAll()
.data(data);

myCircles.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx' , (d) => d.x)
    .attr('cy' , (d) => d.y)
    .attr('r' , (d) => d.radius )
    .attr('fill' , (d) => d.color )

myCircles.attr('fill' , 'orange');
```

**Other things I tried that did not work**

I tried the line

```
d3.selectAll(myCircles).attr('fill' , 'orange');
```

And I tried

```
svg.selectAll(myCircles).attr('fill' , 'orange');
```

But both times recive the error: d3.v7.min.js:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[object Object]' is not a valid selector.

**What does work but I do not want it**

```
d3.selectAll('circle').attr('fill' , 'orange')
```

Because I would like to select the circles by the variable myCircles and not using the d3 tag "circle" as I intend on making more circles later.

Comment: `myCircles` contains the empty **update** selection whereas you are appending to the **enter** selection. To manipulate the circles in the enter selection you need to store a reference to that selection or you need to use [`.merge()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) to merge both selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `myCircles` variable is empty because it is only the update selection, and not the enter selection that appended the circles. If you need a variable to hold the appended circles, you can assign the enter selection to it:

```js
const myCircles = svg.selectAll()
.data(data);

const myOrangeCircles = myCircles.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx' , (d) => d.x)
    .attr('cy' , (d) => d.y)
    .attr('r' , (d) => d.radius )
    .attr('fill' , (d) => d.color )

myOrangeCircles.attr('fill' , 'orange');
```

A good resource I recommend to learn more about those details is the official [General Update Pattern Tutorial](https://observablehq.com/@d3/general-update-pattern)

---

#### To complement:

Instead of variables, you can also use classes to differentiate between objects. For example, if you append the circles with a class, you can later use `selectAll` to retrieve only the circles that match the class:

```js
myCircles.enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx' , (d) => d.x)
    .attr('cy' , (d) => d.y)
    .attr('r' , (d) => d.radius )
    .attr('fill' , (d) => d.color )
    .classed('myOrangeCircle', true)

svg.selectAll('circle.myOrangeCircle').attr('fill' , 'orange');
```

Comment: Thank you hugely Rodrigo! From now on I will use the first method you showed always! I also like using classes and just write .attr('class' , 'classname') for that but it can be fiddly requiring to add a . before the string when using it :)